# Will adding new Service to AndroidManifest stop auto update?

Tags: android

I want users that have an older version of my app to auto-update from google play. I've read that adding new permissions will require the user to manually confirm an update (it still gives notification, but user just has to manually accept).

what about adding Services to the Android Manifest?

Sorry if this question seems trivial - couldn't find this question on stack overflow and definitely do NOT want to release a new version without confirming this

Comment: why u need service, there is no relation between update and service

Comment: great. so in other words, if i add a new service ".BlahService", all my users will still get an auto update?

Comment: as Denis said if you make any change in permission means, there is need of user permission to update your app.

Comment: @CoolMonster - not exactly any change: downgrading permissions (removing existing without adding any new) would not require additional user's approval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Adding new permissions cause stopping auto-update. The reason is that when user installs an app he confirms the set of requested permissions. If the update adds any new permission to this set it should be explicitly approved by user.

Services, receivers, activities do not require user's confirmation during install, thus such confirmation is not needed during update.